# How to get contact form to work

Tags: php, html

Hi guys i am new to php but trying my best so far. I have created a simple form in html :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="contact" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method ="post">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4>Contact:</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="contact-name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact-name" placeholder="First & Last Name">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="contact-email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="contact-email" placeholder="example@sussex.ac.uk">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="contact-message" id ="contact-message" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="6"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>



            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
                <button type="submit1" id ="workinghere1" class="btn btn-warning" onclick ="alert('Email has been sent')">Send</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

and then created a simple php script for it:

```
<?php
f(isset($_POST['workinghere'])){
    $n = $_POST['contact-name'];
    $e = $_POST['contact-email'];
    $m = $_POST['contact-message'];

    $to = "*****************";
    $subject = "WEB 3d";
    $header = $e;
    $server = "smtp.live.com﻿";
    $body = $m;
    mail($to, $subject, $body, $header);
}
?>
```

However for some reason the php script i dont think is working as no email is being sent to my address at all, i am not sure what to do , any help on this matter would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The from address needs to be prefixed with "From: someone@somewhere.com" so the following should work.  Also, all inputs that you read with PHP need to have a name attribute.

```
if(isset($_POST['workinghere'])){
    $n = $_POST['contact-name'];
    $e = "From: ".$_POST['contact-email']."\r\n";
    $m = $_POST['contact-message'];

    $to = "*****************";
    $subject = "WEB 3d";
    $header = $e;
    $server = "smtp.live.com";
    $body = $m;
    mail($to, $subject, $body, $header);
}

<div class="modal fade" id="contact" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method ="post">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4>Contact:</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="contact-name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contact-name" id="contact-name" placeholder="First & Last Name">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="contact-email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="contact-email" id="contact-email" placeholder="example@sussex.ac.uk">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="contact-message" id ="contact-message" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="6" name="contact-message"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>



            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
                <button type="submit1" name="workinghere" id="workinghere1" class="btn btn-warning" onclick ="alert('Email has been sent')">Send</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ah just tried it but no luck, still no email

Comment: See if adding \r\n to the end of the header works.  I updated my answer so you can see.

Comment: hmm again nothing, really weird, does it work for u?

Comment: I think the problem is that you need to add name attributes to your form tags for them to be recognized by $_POST.  I'll update my answer again to show you what I mean.

Comment: hmm again nothing, its really weird , no email

Comment: Are you getting any errors?  What kind of server are you sending it from(wamp, xampp, shared hosting)

Answer (score 0):

`$e = 'From : name <'.$_POST['contact-email'].'>';`

And you email need opend SMTP first.

Comment: nah not working is well

Comment: Ennn. Can you send mail with sendmail  command in shell?